# Absolute positioned custom dropdown is causing scroll. How to fix this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I have a "main-div" with specific height and a dropdown on bottom part inside it. The dropdown is causing extra scroll. Is there any way to stop causing scroll and make it overlap through the parent div?

(*height and properties of the main div cannot be changed in my real situation*)

```css
  .main-div{
    height: 300px;
    width: 600px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: 2px solid #404040;
  }
  .dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #109fff;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.other-content{
    height: 280px;
    background-color: rgb(80, 210, 166);
}
.button-1{
    background-color: #180f37;
    padding: 10px;
    border: #0f1c40;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
  <div class="main-div">
        <div class="other-content">
            <h4>Scroll down to see the button</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <span class="button-1">Mouse over me</span>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <p>Hello World!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Would it not make more sense if you simply made the drop-down into a "drop-up" in this situation? Otherwise, you will probably need a solution like https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/

Comment: Thank you. But in my real scenario we have drop downs from top to bottom of the container. So drop-up would create problem in top part. Thanks for the link

Comment: .dropdown {
  position: relative; it's scrolling because of this can you add top dropdown instead of down? so it will not take extra space

Comment: .dropdown-content add bottom 25, 30px so scroll will add in top not on bottom

Comment: Sorry the dropdown need to be down side.